# Proof of Berger in "Sur les variétés d’Einstein compactes"

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I would appreciate any reference that contains either a translation or proof of the following interesting observation of Berger ([Sur les variétés d’Einstein compactes, M. Berger paper (in French)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02417787)).

> Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Einstein four-manifold. Then for any
>   $p \in M$ and any orthonormal basis ${e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4}$ of $T_pM$,
>   $$K(e_1, e_2) = K(e_3, e_4),\
> K(e_1, e_3) = K(e_2, e_4),\
> K(e_1, e_4) = K(e_2, e_3).$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: This follows from $Ric(e_1,e_1) = K(e_1,e_2)+K(e_1,e_3)+K(e_1,e_4) = \lambda$ and similar formulas for other $Ric(e_i,e_i)$. Just need to take a certain linear combination of these identities...